# VS2010 "Could not write lines to file".........."Network path not found"

Tags: visual-studio-2010

does anybody know what this error in VS2010 means (i did try google but not much came up for this case on ATI stream)

```
Error   9   error MSB3491: Could not write lines to file "\\samples\\opencl\\bin\\debug\\x86_64\\MatrixMulDoubleVS10.exe.embed.manifest". The network path was not found.   C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets   673
```

Im trying to run the ATI Stream SDK examples

Comment: Too many backslashes.  No idea where they came from of course.

Comment: It says the file: Microsoft.CppCommon.targets 673

Comment: Hey to anybody else, it was because i included backslashes at the end of my directory paths :)

Answer (score 2):

modify \MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets

```
<!--<WriteLinesToFile
      Condition="!EXISTS('$(InputManifest)')"
      File="$(InputManifest)"
      Lines=""
      Overwrite="false"
      Encoding ="Unicode"
     />-->


    <WriteLinesToFile
      Condition="!EXISTS('%(Manifest.OutputManifestFile)')"
      File="%(Manifest.OutputManifestFile)"
      Lines=""
      Overwrite="false"
      Encoding ="Unicode"
     />
```

Answer (score 1):

Leaving the drive qualifier off the output and intermediate directory paths can cause this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had a same error in my downloaded sample which was from VC6++. There were errors because output directory and intermediate directory were not given properly. I corrected them and problem was solved.